# Android Manifest Parser Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an Android program.  All the source code is working fine but something happened in Manifest file that prints this.

What does that error `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED` mean?

```
[2013-04-16 20:11:29 - BingoBangalore] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
[2013-04-16 20:11:29 - BingoBangalore] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-04-16 20:11:29 - BingoBangalore] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: show your manifest file.

Comment: r u using any library

Comment: Edit the question and add the relevant logcat output lines that further describe the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this issue.
Just delete "gen"folder . It build automatically.
Application will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Activity name should be prefixed with "." in your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case usually do following:

- check the manifest-file for syntax errors
- clean your project (e.g. build->clean or delete /bin-folder and sometimes /gen-folder)
- go to the project/package explorer
- right-click on the manifest-file
- VALIDATE!

Everything should be fine now.